Need clarification about swift async / await
I'm moving some stuff from pre-swift 6 dispatch queues to the newer concurrency model and I have a point of confusion that maybe somebody can clear up. It seems that the newer model doesn't actually handle the background-process / callback model, or at least I don't fully understand how this is done from the existing documentation available.
If you have something like
func computePI() async -> [Float] {
    // do some ridiculously long process to compute PI
}

Now if I call this back asynchronously from my main thread
// do some ridiculous computation of PI that takes several seconds.
let π = await computePI()
// continue to do some other stuff.

If I'm not mistaken the calling thread will block on await until the PI computation func completes, so this is more or less idential to computing it in the main thread. I don't understand how this structure can replicate the process of dispatching computePI() and have computePI call back a closure when done.
I understand you can wrap this in a task like
Task {
   let π = await computePI()
}

But doesn't this just shift the problem? Now the onus is on the Task to manage completing of the callback closure, so you've just used all this async/await stuff to complicate the process of dispatch and callback closures that Swift 6 was supposed to clean up.
Please someone tell me what I'm missing here.

"If I'm not mistaken the calling thread will block on await" You are mistaken. That is one of the main important advantages and purposes of async/await: suspension on await does not block anything.

Also it will really help in understanding Swift Concurrency if you stop saying "thread". Think about actors. One does sometimes need to know about the relationship between actors and threads, but mostly no. What you need to know is that if computePI is isolated to an actor that is not the MainActor, it will itself not run on the "main thread". And even if computePI is being awaited by a MainActor Task, the "main thread" is not blocked; other MainActor code can run freely during this suspension. Ain't life grand?

Thanks. I was seeing a lot of verbiage online that looked like 'waiting for the task to complete' - the fact that this wasn't a blocking wait wasn't clear from apple or other sources. Probably a failure between screen and brain...


If I'm not mistaken the calling thread will block on await until the PI computation func completes

You are mistaken. By awaiting an async function, the call does not block. Assuming computePI is a global function, it is not isolated to the main actor, and so it will not even run on the main thread. It will run on some thread in the cooperative thread pool.
If you want to think of this in terms of callbacks/completion handlers, everything that happens after the async function call is what would have been passed as the callback/completion handler.
let someResult = await someAsyncFunction()
print(someResult)
doSomethingElse()

// is similar to

someAsyncFunction { someResult in
    print(someResult)
    doSomethingElse()
}

Using await may look like you are writing synchronous code, since the order of execution is one line after another, but it is in fact asynchronous. Whenever there is an await, execution of the enclosing function is suspended, and the thread can carry on with other things. The enclosing function will resume, when the async operation is done.
That said, Swift Concurrency is not suitable for CPU-intensive things like computing pi. The things you do in computePI presumably is not asynchronous, and so will block whatever thread (from the cooperative thread pool) that is running computePI.
You should not block threads in the cooperative thread pool, so for CPU-intensive tasks, I suggest running it on a DispatchQueue, and then you can wrap that in an async function with withCheckedContinuation.

so if I needed to something immediately after let someResult = await someAsyncFunction() without waiting for someAsyncFunction to finish then how would I do it in the async await world? would I have to first move to a different thread before I await?

@mfaani you can async let x = someAsyncFunction(), then when you do want to await it, await x. If you have an unknown number of these, use a task group.

Sorry. That's not what I wanted to ask. Basically how do call an async function and move on without waiting for its response. Think of a 'fire and forget call'. I want to do something like someAsyncFunction(); //then: executeImmediatelyFunc()

@mfaani Well in that case you can just wrap it in a Task { … } and forget about it. Fire-and-forget is an anti-pattern though - you have no way of cancelling the task, no error handling, etc.

First, as an aside, you generally only declare a function to be async if it has an await of some other asynchronous function(s). And when you await, that will generally not block the current thread.
Second, a word of caution: If you are really doing something that can temporarily block a thread because it really is doing something slow and synchronous, like calculating π, the answer is, unfortunately, “it depends.” Now, the vast majority of the time, when we write an async function, we don’t have to worry about this, because we will await some other async function(s): But in the special case of doing something slow and synchronous, like manually calculating π, the async qualifier, alone, does not magically get it off the current isolation context.
Consider:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    …

    func computePI() async -> Double { // note, if you’re doing something slow and synchronous, the `async` keyword is unnecessary
        // do some ridiculously long process to compute PI
    }
}

Because UIViewController is isolated to the main actor, the computePI will also be isolated to the main actor. As a result, if computePI does something slow and synchronous, it will block the main actor while that is underway (and, therefore, block the main thread, too), despite the presence of the async keyword.
Likewise, this will also block the main actor:
@MainActor
class Foo {
    …

    func computePI() async -> Double { // note, if you’re doing something slow and synchronous, the `async` keyword is unnecessary
        // do some ridiculously long process to compute PI
    }
}

So, if you want to do something slow and synchronous, you want to get it off the current actor. For example, you can put it in its own actor, like so:
actor Calculations {
    func computePI() -> Double {
        // do some ridiculously long process to compute PI
    }
}

That gets computePI off of the context of the caller. (But, if you call computePI multiple times, it will only do one at a time.)
Alternatively, we can define the function to be a nonisolated async function, which by virtue of SE-0338, gets it off the current actor-isolation and runs it on a “generic executor”:
nonisolated func computePI() async -> Double {
    // do some ridiculously long process to compute PI
}

Or you can use a detached task (though unstructured concurrency is generally not advisable):
func computePI() async -> Double {
    let task = Task.detached {
        // do some ridiculously long process to compute PI
    }
    
    return await withTaskCancellationHandler { 
        await task.value
    } onCancel: { 
        task.cancel()
    }
}


All of this having been said, if have something slow and synchronous, we should recognize that we have a contract to never block a thread from the cooperative thread pool of Swift concurrency. So, you have two options:

Periodically try Task.checkCancellation() and await Task.yield; or,

Where performance is important, one might keep it out of Swift concurrency entirely (e.g., use GCD), but then bridge back to Swift concurrency with a continuation.


We should acknowledge that this is “ridiculously long process” is a bit of an edge-case, a more advanced scenario. The vast majority of the time, where an async functions will merely await other async functions, this is not a concern. This is only a consideration when performing work that can block a thread. For more information about this scenario, see point #3 in Convert a sync function to async using new concurrency in Swift.

Now, having answered the question about how to make slow, synchronous work run asynchronously, you then suggest that you want to carry on executing (presumably looking for parallel execution). There are a few patterns for that.
The “calculate π” might not be a great example, so let us consider an example of image processing, where you might want to perform some a slow synchronous work on each image, but do it in parallel:

Use async let:
async let processedImage1 = process(image1)
async let processedImage2 = process(image2)
async let processedImage3 = process(image3)

try await (processedImage1, processedImage2, processedImage3)

That will run those three process functions in parallel, not block the caller’s thread, but will then await all three to finish at the end.

Alternatively, use a “task group”, e.g.:
let images: [UIImage] = …
try await withThrowingDiscardingTaskGroup { group in
    for image in images {
        group.addTask { try await process(image) }
    }
}



There are other variations on the idea, but these sorts of patterns enable you to proceed execution while the asynchronous work is underway.

To expand on Sweeper's answer, I think that you have used the term "Thread", which has a specific meaning, when you really probably mean execution flow generically.
When you said

If I'm not mistaken the calling thread will block on await until the PI computation func completes

maybe you were actually trying to say "execution of the current code block will be suspended until the PI computation function completes".
And this is correct.  One of the benefits of async/await is that you can write code that invokes some asynchronous operation in a linear way. A classic example is fetching some data from the network:
var total = 0
let count = await getDataFromNetwork()
total += count
print(total)

Here, the add operationneeds the result of the network operation and so execution of the code block is suspended until that operation completes and the result can be used without having to write "non-linear" code.
This is much simpler to understand than the older closure/callback style:
var total = 0
getDataFromNetwork() { count in
    total += count
}
print(total)

This would print 0 because we are accessing total outside the closure, before the asynchronous work is complete.
The use case you describe is for long-running or computationally intensive operations.  In your example, if the next line of code needed the value of π then the await would be correct; execution of the code block cannot continue until π is available.
In the comment in your example you say "// continue to do some other stuff.".  This implies that the following code does need the value of π to continue.  In this case you need to use something to dispatch computePI concurrently. Unstructured concurrency via Task is one way, as is GCD dispatch, which as Sweeper said, is the better choice in this case.
